# How to read all songs from internal and external directory in Android Java?

Tags: java, android

I am newbie to android. I am developing the music player using media player in android. The app is running fine but it reads songs only in phone. And one more thing since getExternalStorageDirectory is deprecated so how can i read the files and songs. Please resolve this Issue.

```
readMusicFiles(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());

 public void readMusicFiles(File directory)
{
    File[] files = directory.listFiles();

    for(File file:files){

        if(file.isDirectory() && !file.isHidden()){
            readMusicFiles(file);
        }
        else
        {
            if(file.getName().endsWith(".mp3")){
                FileModel model = new FileModel();
                model.setFile(file);
                fileModelList.add(model);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In new versions of Android 6.0+ you should use SAF(Storage Access Framework). It's pretty big one to answer here. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider

Comment: For media, query the `MediaStore`, please. It already has an index of all available media content.

Comment: Thankyou very much...